# Cloudera Manager - Service Monitor is not running

Tags: cloudera-manager

It seems there is something wrong with connection issues.But I don't know what lead to this problem.Could anyone help me?What connection issue am I facing?

```
(9 skipped) Error sending messages to firehose: mgmt-SERVICEMONITOR-73cd125b24d5013535b3d65d46703b65
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cm-5.13.0/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cmf-5.13.0-py2.6.egg/cmf/monitor/firehose.py", line 116, in _send
    self._port)
  File "/opt/cm-5.13.0/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 469, in __init__
    self.conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/httplib.py", line 720, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 567, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that CM agent is not able to reach out to Service Monitor due to `Connection refused`.

The most common reason is Service Monitor not running. Check if Service Monitor is actually running.

Another reason could be CM agent is not able to connect Service Monitor on port 9997. Check from CM agent host using

```
telnet <SMON_Host> 9997
```